# When I answer my own question and accept it I lose 15 reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer

Hello everybody, I am new to SO. I ask a question and didn't get an good answer for a week. Now, to maintain my accept rate, I answer it myself and I accept that answer. Next day I saw a loss of 15 reputation. Why did this happen? There may be some other reason, but I think nothing will decrease reputation by 15. I hadn't set bounty on my question.

Comment: Just to add to S.Mark's answer; if you go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation you should be able to account for everything.

Comment: @Marc Is there any link on my user page for stackoverflow.com/reputation ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't lose or gain reputation from accepting own answers.

Probably, you got 2 downvotes in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801258/2801371#2801371) post, which is -4 and may be someone revoked upvote on your answer, which will be -10, so most likely you lost -14 in total, if you remember you had 90+ the other day.

Comment: @S.Mark I didn't understand 'someone revoked upvote on your answer, which will be -10'???? I saw my reputaion was 103 yesterday.

Comment: @Himadri, for example, someone upvoted one of your answer, you got +10 right, but if they undo it later on (probably within 5 minutes), then you lost your +10, so apparently you lose -10.

Comment: oh, 103? so probably, someone revoked the accepted answer. its 15 points, now you have 84, there is -4 from downvotes, another -15 could be from unaccepted answer. 84+4+15 is 103

Comment: probably, your answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801258/displaying-images-in-asp-page/2801371#2801371) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800519/is-the-set-of-data-always-normalized-in-one-form-or-the-other-in-databases/2800541#2800541) question was accepted before, but question owner notice that other answer is better, so he accepted different answer, and in the meantime you got 2 downvotes, so basically you lose -15 and -4, which results in 84 from 103.

Comment: @S.Mark OK..Thanks. You are right. My answer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793470/how-to-split-strings-and-bind-them-as-header-for-gridview/2793572#2793572 was accepted before. Now I got every thing. Thank You.

Comment: Welcome @Himadri